# How to avoid "trap" with linear interpolation?

Tags: c++, linear-interpolation

I have a range `a` (starting range) and a range `b` (target range), and I need to scale a value `aX` from range `a` to range `b`. Code is a basic linear interpolation:

```
double LinearInterpolation(double a0, double a1, double b0, double b1, double aX) {
    return b0 + (b1 - b0) * (aX - a0) / (a1 - a0);
}
```

The fact is: range b can be 0-length from 1.0 to 1.0. But when I reach that range, I got a value that is "trap", and can't go back. [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a296e791e6b3cbee) an example:

```
int main ()
{
    double a0 = 0.4;
    double a1 = 1.0;
    double b0 = 0.6;
    double b1 = 1.0;

    double aX = 0.58;

    aX = LinearInterpolation(a0, a1, b0, b1, aX);
    std::cout << aX << std::endl;

    b0 = 1.0;
    aX = LinearInterpolation(a0, a1, b0, b1, aX);
    std::cout << aX << std::endl;

    b0 = 0.6;
    aX = LinearInterpolation(a0, a1, b0, b1, aX);
    std::cout << aX << std::endl;    
}
```

Until `b0` is 0, it scales correctly the `aX` value. When I reach `b0 = b1 = 1.0`, I can't go back (`aX` is always 1.0, because a`X = a1`, thus is always  `b0 + (b1 - b0) => b1`).

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I avoid this?

Don't store the actual value, but rather the relative position within a range:

```
struct value_in_range {
  double normalized_offset;
  double in_range (double from, double to) const {
    return from + (to - from) * normalized_offset;
  }
};

value_in_range make_value_in_range (double from, double value, double to) {
  // Add assertions to avoid misuse
  return {(value - from) / (to - from)};
}
```

With your example:

```
int main ()
{
    double a0 = 0.4;
    double a1 = 1.0;
    double b0 = 0.6;
    double b1 = 1.0;

    double aX = 0.58;

    value_in_range X = make_value_in_range (a0, aX, a1);

    std::cout << X.in_range(b0, b1) << std::endl;

    b0 = 1.0;
    std::cout << X.in_range(b0, b1) << std::endl;

    b0 = 0.6;
    std::cout << X.in_range(b0, b1) << std::endl;
}
```

You could also set `aX` as in your original code.

Comment: what's normalized_offset?

Comment: The member storing (basically) the percentage of how far from start to end of the range the value lies. 0 is it's at the start, 1 if at the end.

Comment: Now sure how you store the return of make_value_in_range to normalized_offset :O